# TFS2010 integration tests fail on DB connection

Tags: mstest

I am re-writing some tests that were written in nUnit because TFS2010 integrates better with MSTest.exe I completed about 70 unit test and the TFS build is now set to not deploy the website if a tests fail, wohooo!!!

Now I have to do the integration tests that actually tests by using the database repository on our build server (only used for build tests) I have about 40 tests for my user repository and if I run it locally in VS2010 (connecting to the build db) it runs fine. Once I check this in and my CI build fires a build it fails on the integration tests. A few +-4 tests execute fine and then it starts with : "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server" Some of the tests succeed and some fail but locally they are all fine.

I get the idea it is because MSTest is multi-threaded so that numerous tests can start at the same time, correct? Without increasing the connection pool for SQL, how am I going to get past this?

Thank you

Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hint on trying the ordered list. My problem was actually the fact that there was a problem and my MSTest could not connect to the database where my integration tests were hoping to run.

I found this by running the tests on my TFS server (I just thought that this is where TFS was going to run the test so I should too..) from the command prompt. Once I saw it was failing every test I tried to use sqlcmd to connect to the database that the tests were using and that failed so problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the unit tests that you are concenred about in an [Ordered List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx)?

[Setting Up Your Test Run Sequence Using Ordered Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286704.aspx)